# Как вызвать поочередно команды GIT из файла (блокнота)?

Tags: git

Нужно из под `gitbash` вызвать файл, но главный вопрос - это как сделать так, чтобы в файле поочередно выполнялись команды после запуска файла?

Например: нужно, чтобы вызвалась команда `checkout` (чтобы переключить релиз), затем `Pull`, чтобы обновить локально объекты и вытащить какую либо информацию (например командой `git --name-status`).

Comment: Что за gitbush? Какая ОС?

Comment: Так скриптик же написать, не?

Comment: А вообще учитывая что каждая команда ваша может провалится - автоматически вызов их подряд может дать неожиданный результат.

Comment: @Mira: да вроде скриптик и нужен.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не хочется скрипт за кого-то писать )

Answer (score 1):

Создайте скрипт (специальный файл с командами, при запуске которого ОС эти команды выполняет в командной строке). В windows это расширения `*.bat  *.cmd`. В Linux файл скрипта делается исполняемым командой `chmod +x myScript`.

Но как написано в комментарии - команды гита далеко не всегда завершаются успешно, потому лучше их выполнять ручками по одной.

Comment: А почему бы не использовать средства bash/cmd для проверки кода выхода команд git? ;)

Comment: Как бы да, но что вы будете делать, когда checkout вернет вам фэйл? Что вообще полагается делать автоматически в таких случаях? В том плане что принять решение собственной головой проще намного, чем прописать инструкции для всех случаев.

Comment: Это вопрос к ТС а не ко мне. А насчет принятия решения вручную -- это слишком рутинные операции чтобы каждый раз о них думать. Да и на практике checkout не так уж часто вываливается))

Comment: @Mira, в bash/sh есть опция "-e", которая прекращает работу скрипта после первой ошибки. В cmd не в курсе.